# Iterate through a file and process it

Tags: python, csv, python-3.4

So I want to have a function that can read through a file and be able to count the stuff in them. So far I have this:

```
import csv
def get_stats(train_file, valid_pfile = "cmu-phonemes.txt", valid_graphemes = 
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o',
 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '_'}):

    invalid_row = 0
    valid_row = 0
    phonemes_count = 0
    graphemes_count = 0
    underscore_count = 0

    csv_open = open(train_file)
    reader = csv.reader(csv_open)

    with open(valid_pfile) as valid_p:
        valid_pset = set(line.strip() for line in valid_p)
    valid_gset = set(valid_graphemes)
```

As you might suspect I want to count out the numbers of some specific stuff. But that is not necessarily hard. The thing is I cannot figure out a way to iterate through the file and do some further counting to it.

Here is a sample file:

```
phonemes,graphemes
W IY K D EY,w ee k d ay
T EH K S T,t e x _ t
Y UW,ewe _
SH UW T,chu te
SH UW T,chu te
SH UW T,chu te !
SX AH K,s u ck
```

The question is how do I iterate through the file and separate them by that "," in the middle(csv format)
So I could have something like

```
[["SH", "UW", "T"],["chu", "te"]]
```

Or something like this that can be used for looping and check.

Comment: Have you tried `line.split(',')` ?

Comment: You appear to be iterating through the file already.  Is it `line.split(',')` you are looking for?  What else do you need?

Comment: @cdarke that would actually make two different lists or container objects?

Comment: One list for each call to `split()`, so one per iteration.  Which type of container you need, and what you do with the list, depends on your application, i.e. what you intend to do with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file_output = []
with open(valid_pfile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines()[1:]: # ignoring the first line which is header
       file_output.append([v.split() for v in line.split(',')])
```

After this block the value of `file_output` will be:

```
[[['W', 'IY', 'K', 'D', 'EY'], ['w', 'ee', 'k', 'd', 'ay']],
 [['T', 'EH', 'K', 'S', 'T'], ['t', 'e', 'x', '_', 't']],
 [['Y', 'UW'], ['ewe', '_']],
 [['SH', 'UW', 'T'], ['chu', 'te']],
 [['SH', 'UW', 'T'], ['chu', 'te']],
 [['SH', 'UW', 'T'], ['chu', 'te', '!']],
 [['SX', 'AH', 'K'], ['s', 'u', 'ck']]]
```

Now, you can use this the way you want to.